# react-native で andorid アプリを起動しようとするとエラーが発生する

Tags: react-native

[この質問には自ら回答しました]

react-native で android アプリを起動しようとすると下記のようなエラーが発生します

```
$ react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
.
.
.
:app:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.053 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

これは何が原因なんでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

仮想デバイスが見つからないことによるエラーです

```
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

これは仮想デバイスがネットワーク上に見つからずデバイスに接続できないということを意味しています
実際にandroid デバイスを探すコマンドでも

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

となります。

Android の仮想デバイスを起動してください。
Android の仮想デバイスエミュレーターとしてオススメなのが [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) です。

1. GenyMotionのサイトでアカウントを作成して GenyMotion をダウンロード
2. GenyMotion をインストール
3. GenyMotion を起動して自分の使いたいデバイスを選んでデバイスを起動

するとホスト側のＯＳでは

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.56.101:5555 device
```

となりデバイスがネットワーク上に現れますので

```
 $ react-native run-android
```

で Android を起動してください

[ここ](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html)を参考にしました